# Incorporating external function in R's apply

Tags: r, function, apply

Given this data.frame

```
  x y z
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6
```

I'd like to add the value of columns *x* and *z* plus a coefficient 10, for every rows in `dat`.
The intended result is this

```
  x y z result
1 1 3 5 16      #(1+5+10)
2 2 4 6 18      #(2+6+10)
```

But why this code doesn't produce the desired result?

```
 dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4), z=c(5,6))
 Coeff <- 10

 # Function
 process.xz <- function(v1,v2,cf) {
    return(v1+v2+cf)
 }

# It breaks here
sm <- apply(dat[,c('x','z')], 1, process.xz(dat$x,dat$y,Coeff ))

# Later I'd do this:
# cbind(dat,sm);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use an `apply` here. Since the addition `+` operator is vectorized, you can get the sum using

```
> process.xz(dat$x, dat$z, Coeff)
[1] 16 18
```

To write this in your `data.frame`, don't use `cbind`, just assign it directly:

```
dat$result <- process.xz(dat$x, dat$z, Coeff)
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason it fails is because apply doesn't work like that - you must pass the name of a function and any additional parameters. The rows of the data frame are then passed (as a single vector) as the first argument to the function named.

```
 dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4), z=c(5,6))
 Coeff <- 10

 # Function
 process.xz <- function(x,cf) {
    return(x[1]+x[2]+cf)
 }

sm <- apply(dat[,c('x','z')], 1, process.xz,cf=Coeff)
```

I completely agree that there's no point in using apply here though - but it's good to understand anyway.